# using iframe in phonegap app

Tags: cordova, iframe

I am using iframe in my phonegap app to open an external website. Website is open up but it has horizontal scrolling. While if I open same website in browser of mobile it opens up properly without horizontal scrolling. I have used width and height as 100% as well set width as screen width 320 or others but could not resolve problem. Same problem I am facing with other website.
Can you please help me.

[image]

Website on mobile browser

[image]

Website in iframe in app

Comment: Put your iframe inside the div `<div id="content" style="height: auto; width: auto; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;">
   
  </div>`

Comment: @Aravin I have done the same. but problem persists.

Comment: include this in your iframe style `height="100%" scrolling="no" width="100%"`

Answer (score 0):

Before i face the similar issue like yours, i solved using the below method. Put your iframe inside the following `div` it will  scroll the entire webpage inside your phonegap .

```
<div id="content" style="height: auto; width: auto; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;">
        <iframe height="100%" scrolling="no" width="100% "> iframe content here </iframe>
</div>
```